# Scapy and TCP stack: avoid the TCP stack of my system to send an RST

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, scapy

I have the following scapy scipt

```
a=IP(dst="192.168.10.71")/TCP(sport=13998, dport=14010, flags="S", window=1400)
sr1(a)
a=IP(dst="192.168.10.71")/TCP(sport=13998, dport=14010, flags="A", window=1400)
sr1(a)
```

The first packet is sent to the destination tcp server
[image]

Then I received an SYN+ACK from the TCP server:
[image]

Then look that the TCP stack of my system send an RST TCP packet, befor that my script send the second TCP packet (ACK) as indicated in the above script

[image]

How to avoid the TCP stack of my sytem to send the RST TCP packet after receiving the SYN+ACK from the server? and send instead of it my second TCP packet as indicated in the script?

By the way my TCP server is:

```
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:14010", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  echo "SERVER TCP (port 14010) started!";
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    fwrite($conn, 'The local time is ' . date('n/j/Y g:i a') . "\n");
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
?>
```

Comment: I assume 192.168.10.71 is server and the client is 192.168.2.68.

I think something is wrong with the server. The `ACK` sent from the server  would normally not be zero. Because it should normally be `Client initial sequence number + 1`. In this case the `ACK` sent from the server should have the value `1`. Also I suppose as the server sent an invalid ACK, the client will send a `RST` instead of the `ACK`, because client is not sure if this is the server to whom it sent the `SYN` in first packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is in the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058052/unwanted-rst-tcp-packet-with-scapy):

should add this ip table command

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s 192.168.2.68 -j DROP
```