# How to create HTTP GET request Scapy?

Tags: python, http, get, scapy

I need to create HTTP GET request and save the data response.
I tried to use this:

```
    syn = IP(dst=URL) / TCP(dport=80, flags='S')
    syn_ack = sr1(syn)
    getStr = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n'
    request = IP(dst='www.google.com') / TCP(dport=80, sport=syn_ack[TCP].dport,
            seq=syn_ack[TCP].ack, ack=syn_ack[TCP].seq + 1, flags='A') / getStr
    reply = sr1(request)
    print reply.show()
```

But when I print `reply` I don't see any data response.
In addition, when I checked in 'Wireshark' I got SYN, SYN/ACK but I didn't get an ACK.

Image:
[image: The problem]

Edit:

I try to do that now:

```
# Import scapy
from scapy.all import *

# Print info header
print "[*] ACK-GET example -- Thijs 'Thice' Bosschert, 06-06-2011"

# Prepare GET statement
get='GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n'

# Set up target IP
ip=IP(dst="www.google.com")

# Generate random source port number
port=RandNum(1024,65535)

# Create SYN packet
SYN=ip/TCP(sport=port, dport=80, flags="S", seq=42)

# Send SYN and receive SYN,ACK
print "\n[*] Sending SYN packet"
SYNACK=sr1(SYN)

# Create ACK with GET request
ACK=ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=80, flags="A", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1) / get

# SEND our ACK-GET request
print "\n[*] Sending ACK-GET packet"
reply,error=sr(ACK)

# print reply from server
print "\n[*] Reply from server:"
print reply.show()

print '\n[*] Done!'
```

but its print me in reply from server;

> 0000 IP / TCP 192.168.44.130:23181 > 216.58.208.164:http A / Raw ==>
>   IP / TCP 216.58.208.164:http > 192.168.44.130:23181 A / Padding None

And I need Line-based text data: text/html.

Comment: reply.show() already prints itself, there is no need for the print statement

Comment: @YotamSalmon but i need only the data for save it in html file.

Comment: B I know you do, but the reply variable is an Object, and not a String. You have to get the response load from the object. I don't remember how right now, but let me check and I'll post an answer soon if I find the solution. Is this question for Magshimim project in Networks?

Comment: @YotamSalmon Yes, I tried for a long time and I i did not succeed

Comment: Well, I'm sorry. I tried so hard, and yet couldn't find a solution. By the way, I would recommend taking a look at this website: ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @YotamSalmon Yes I know, my english is not very good :(

Comment: Well, sorry for sounding offensive. I recommended because this website helped me a lot with my English (Which used to be terrible)... Hope you do understand that comment was not meant to offend or laugh at you.

Comment: @YotamSalmon Yes, thank you for comment, but how this site can help me ?

Comment: Err, just reading and trying to answer questions surprisingly improves your English skills.

Comment: Try posting your question here: http://magshimim.online/ There are people here that have already finished the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a SYN and correctly receiving a SYN_ACK. At this point, you should generate and send an ACK based on the SYN_ACK that you've received, and THEN finally transmit the HTTP GET request. It seems that you are somewhat confused about the TCP 3-way handshake mechanism. In short, you are not supposed to 'get' an ACK, you are supposed to generate and send this yourself.

Comment: So you can fix my code, I try and it also don't working for me.

Comment: @YairB. Firstly, have you implemented the workaround that was mentioned earlier to get around the RST issue? First ensure that RST does not get automatically sent by your OS. Then try generating an ACK in response to the SYN_ACK. If this doesn't work, please upload a new wireshark capture at this point then we can take it from there.

Comment: @wookie919 He is already acknowledging the SYN-ACK in its `request` segment, however, you are right, it is good practice to send an ACK without data before the actual request as this is a faster way to acknowledge segments (and establish the connection in this example).

Comment: Now I update question.. Look what I try to do and what its print me.

Answer (score 3):

You are sending a RST segment in response to the SYN-ACK because your kernel has no knowledge of the SYN you sent via Scapy (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058052/unwanted-rst-tcp-packet-with-scapy)). This could be solved with an iptable rule:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s <your ip> -j DROP`

Because you are ending the connection with that RST segment, when you send your HTTP request, the endpoint answers with a RST too because connection is not established and so you are using `show()` on a RST segment with no data, that is why you do not see anything.

Answer (score 2):

After setting the rule in your iptables as has been suggested above, you could do the following :

```
from scapy.all import *

seq = 12345
sport = 1040
dport = 80

ip_packet = IP(dst='192.168.56.107')
syn_packet = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='S', seq=seq)

packet = ip_packet/syn_packet
synack_response = sr1(packet)

next_seq = seq + 1
my_ack = synack_response.seq + 1

ack_packet = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='A', seq=next_seq, ack=my_ack)

send(ip_packet/ack_packet)

payload_packet = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='A', seq=next_seq, ack=my_ack)
payload = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHOST: 192.168.56.107\r\n\r\n"

reply, error = sr(ip_packet/payload_packet/payload, multi=1, timeout=1)
for r in reply:
    r[0].show2()
    r[1].show2()
```

Hope this helps. Basically, the first response you get back does not really hold the  HTTP response data. I tested the script against an INETSIM simulated HTTP server and in that case (at least) the first packet (after the 3-way TCP handshake) that the server responded with was a series of NULL (0x00) bytes. Hence using multi somehow did the stuff in my case.