# when i made a 3 handshake with ubuntu in VMware return package R

Tags: python, http, package, virtual-machine, scapy

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

def findWeb():
    a = sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP()/DNS(qd=DNSQR(qname="www.google.com")),verbose=0)
    return a[DNSRR].rdata

def sendPacket(dst,src):
    ip = IP(dst = dst)
    SYN = TCP(sport=1500, dport=80, flags='S')
    SYNACK = sr1(ip/SYN)

    my_ack = SYNACK.seq + 1
    ACK = TCP(sport=1050, dport=80, flags='A', ack=my_ack)
    send(ip/ACK)

    payload = "stuff"
    PUSH = TCP(sport=1050, dport=80, flags='PA', seq=11, ack=my_ack)
    send(ip/PUSH/payload)


    http = sr1(ip/TCP()/'GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \n\n',verbose=0)
    print http.show()

src = '10.0.0.24'
dst = findWeb()
sendPacket(dst,src)
```

I'm trying to do HTTP packets with SCAPY
I am using UBUNTU on VMwaer

The problem is that every time I send messages I have RESET
How do we fix it?

Thanks

[sniff package image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eJdj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Few things I notice wrong. 
1. You have your sequence number set statically (seq=11) which is wrong. Sequence numbers are always randomly generated and they must be used as per RFC793. So the sequence should be = SYNACK[TCP].ack

2. You set your source port as 1500 during SYN packet, but then you use it as 1050 (typo?)
3. You don't need extra payload/PUSH.

Also, have a look at these threads:

[How to create HTTP GET request Scapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683026/how-to-create-http-get-request-scapy)

[Python-Scapy or the like-How can I create an HTTP GET request at the packet level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750793/python-scapy-or-the-like-how-can-i-create-an-http-get-request-at-the-packet-leve)