# Scapy Packet Based HTTP Client Not Showing HTML?

Tags: python, scapy

I've looked at:
[How to create HTTP GET request Scapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683026/how-to-create-http-get-request-scapy/37696246)
[Python-Scapy or the like-How can I create an HTTP GET request at the packet level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750793/python-scapy-or-the-like-how-can-i-create-an-http-get-request-at-the-packet-leve)

So you send syn to get syn-ack, then you send ack along with the HTTP load.

And then the reply is this:

`<IP  version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=40 id=0 flags=DF frag=0 ttl=64 proto=tcp chksum=0x6197 src=!!!! dst=!!!! |<TCP  sport=http dport=ftp_data seq=2913655423 ack=0 dataofs=5 reserved=0 flags=R window=0 chksum=0x4e19 urgptr=0 |>>`

Which isn't HTTP at all.

Comment: It might be. sport=http means it's using an http port. To check whether there's actually an HTTP layer, you'd open wireshark. Occasionally you need to decode as layer to see it.

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't scapy give me the http layer?

Comment: No. TCP syn/ack still happens on port 80. Check google for how TCP works